# The import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer conflicts with a type defined in the same file. Help :(

Tags: java, eclipse, web-frontend

I'm trying to make a web front end for a database using Java in Eclipse and I get this error message:

"The import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer conflicts with a type defined in the same file"

I have done something similar in other Eclipse projects and I don't encounter this problem and it works. Yet I am getting this error in another project.

I can't work out where to even begin in fixing it. Help :(

Comment: You seem to be importing this class in a file defining a class also named HttpServer, as the error message says. What is your code?

Comment: That is exactly what I was doing. Which also explains why my code worked in other projects where I had called the class something else. Thanks. Problem solved :)

Comment: So, understanding what the error message meant helped you fix the problem?

Comment: Yes. I was totally blind to what was an obvious problem/fix.